# How to include batch normalization in non-sequential keras model

Tags: deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, batch-normalization, nonsequential

I am new to DL and Keras. Currently I try to implement a Unet-like CNN and now I want to include batch normalization layers into my non-sequential model but do not really now how.

That is my current try to include it:

```
input_1 = Input((X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2], X_train.shape[3]))

conv1 = Conv2D(16, (3,3), strides=(2,2), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_1)
batch1 = BatchNormalization(axis=3)(conv1)
conv2 = Conv2D(32, (3,3), strides=(2,2), activation='relu', padding='same')(batch1)
batch2 = BatchNormalization(axis=3)(conv2)
conv3 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), strides=(2,2), activation='relu', padding='same')(batch2)
batch3 = BatchNormalization(axis=3)(conv3)
conv4 = Conv2D(128, (3,3), strides=(2,2), activation='relu', padding='same')(batch3)
batch4 = BatchNormalization(axis=3)(conv4)
conv5 = Conv2D(256, (3,3), strides=(2,2), activation='relu', padding='same')(batch4)
batch5 = BatchNormalization(axis=3)(conv5)
conv6 = Conv2D(512, (3,3), strides=(2,2), activation='relu', padding='same')(batch5)
drop1 = Dropout(0.25)(conv6)

upconv1 = Conv2DTranspose(256, (3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='same')(drop1)
upconv2 = Conv2DTranspose(128, (3,3), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(upconv1)
upconv3 = Conv2DTranspose(64, (3,3), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(upconv2)
upconv4 = Conv2DTranspose(32, (3,3), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(upconv3)
upconv5 = Conv2DTranspose(16, (3,3), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(upconv4)
upconv5_1 = concatenate([upconv5,conv2], axis=3)
upconv6 = Conv2DTranspose(8, (3,3), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(upconv5_1)
upconv6_1 = concatenate([upconv6,conv1], axis=3)
upconv7 = Conv2DTranspose(1, (3,3), strides=(2,2), activation='linear', padding='same')(upconv6_1)

model = Model(outputs=upconv7, inputs=input_1)
```

Is the batch normalization used in the right way? In the keras documentation I read that you typically want to normalize the "features axis"!?
This is a short snippet out of the model summary:

```
====================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)             (None, 512, 512, 9)   0
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)                (None, 256, 256, 16)  1312        input_1[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)                (None, 128, 128, 32)  4640        conv2d_1[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)                (None, 64, 64, 64)    18496       conv2d_2[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

In this case my features axis is axis 3(start counting at 0), right?
I read about discussions whether you should implement the batch normalization before or after the activation function. In this case it is used after the activation function, right? Is there a possibility to use it before the activation function?

Thank you very much for your help and feedback! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Part 1: Is the batch normalization used in the right way?**
The way you've called the BatchNormalization layer is correct; axis=3 is what you want, as recommended by the documentation.
Keep in mind that in the case of your model, axis=3 is equivalent to the default setting, axis=-1, so you do not need to call it explicitly.
**Part 2: In this case it is used after the activation function, right? Is there a possibility to use it before the activation function?**
Yes, batch normalization as defined in [the 2014 research paper by Ioffe and Szegedy](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03167.pdf) is intended for use after the activation layer as a means of reducing internal covariate shift. Your code correctly applies the batchnorm after the activations on your convolutional layers. Its use after the activation layer can be thought of as a "pre-processing step" for the information before it reaches the next layer as an input.
For that reason, batch normalization can also serve as a data pre-processing step, which you can use immediately after your input layer (as discussed in [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46771939/batch-normalization-instead-of-input-normalization).) However, as that answer mentions, batchnorm should not be abused; it's computationally expensive and can force your model into approximately linear behavior ([this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/296680/input-layer-batch-normalization/299377#299377) goes into more detail about this issue).
Using batchnorm in some other step in the model (not after activation layer or input layer) would have poorly-understood effects on model performance; it's a process intended explicitly to be applied to the outputs of the activation layer.
In my experience with u-nets, I've had a lot of success applying batchnorm only after the convolutional layers before max pooling; this effectively doubles the computational "bang for my buck" on normalization, since these tensors are re-used in the u-net architecture. Aside from that, I don't use batchnorm (except maybe on the inputs if the mean pixel intensities per image are super heterogeneous.)

Answer (score -2):

axis 3 = axis -1 which is the default parameter.

Comment: Does this add anything more than the other answer?